# Outlook for Android "no app installed to open this" but it's just a link

Tags: android, html, html-email

I have an automated system that sends HTML emails. The link in the email works fine on the desktop version of Outlook. But when I tried to open the Android version of Outlook, it is based on "render://init-bundle/" and my URL follows as "render://init-bundle/www.website.com".
I saw an answer saying that I need to put the entire address, with https:// or http://, but I did that and it didn't help.

Could anyone explain to me why this happens and how I can resolve it?